# 要素のid属性を削除したい

Tags: javascript, html, onsen-ui

属性の削除についてお尋ねしたいことがあります。
以下にhtml文を載せます。
タグの中にあるid="newsitem"をjavascriptを使用して削除したいのですが、どのようにすればよろしいですか？
ご教授よろしくお願いします。

menu.html

```
　　<ons-list-item id="newsitem"
        modifier="tappable" class="list__item__line-height"
        onclick="app.slidingMenu.setMainPage('news.html', {closeMenu: true})">
        <i class="fa fa-list fa-lg" style="color: #666"></i>
        &nbsp; ニュース
    </ons-list-item>
```

Comment: `id="newsitem"` が指定されている `<ons-list-item>` 要素を削除したいのか、このタグに対する `id="newsitem"` という指定を削除したいのか、どちらでしょうか？

Comment: タイトルで混乱させてしまいすみません。
私が行いたいことは、このタグに対する id="newsitem" という指定を削除したいこととなります。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 4):

属性を削除するには、要素に対し[`removeAttribute()`メソッド](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute)を実行します。

```
var elm = document.getElementById("newsitem");
elm.removeAttribute("id");
```